# safe user authentification without javascript

Tags: javascript, hash, passwords, plaintext

I consider Javascript a security risk, therefore I would like to allow users of my website to login without having to have Javascript enabled.

This brings me to another problem. Without client-side-scripting I have no idea how I can hash the users password at the client side so to avoid plaintext password transmission.
How can "pure HTML+CSS" allow me to have a password hashed.

At present it seems to me the only safe option (without Javascript) would be to have a secure(encrypted) ssl/https connection and send password as plaintext?

Anyhow: Is there some way to hash the users password as to avoid to send it over the internet in plaintext.? Is this possible only using client-side-scripting?

[update]
I am aware that SSL is maybe the most close to ideal way. (as mentioned in the comments) Anyhow. It would be already an security improvement when at no time a plaintext username and plaintext password would be send via an unsafe channel. The hashes can be sniffed as well and no safty (i.e encryption) can be there.  BUT at no time a sniffer will be able to get the unhased version of the username and password. => advantage would be that users will not make public their username/password combination (potentially used elsewhere).

After all it seems like there is no "scripting disabled"-way of (spice)hashing some input-field values. So I assume my question is unsolveable.

Comment: does "SSL" ring any bells? SSL was made for this purpose. There is no real "security" for HTML+CSS even with JS.

Comment: I would implement the encryption in JavaScript and if the user has JavaScript disabled I would inform him about the unsecure transmission (using HTML's noscript-tag: `<noscript>Warning</noscript>`).
But still the best and I guess most common solution is the transmission via a secure connection (HTTPS).

Comment: ... or use HTTPS and Client-certificates

Comment: you could even use the TLS-SRP (secure remote password via SSL) extension for browsers that support it.

Comment: @Joseph I am aware, no 100% securtiy. But (spice)hashing passwords makes capturing (by sniffing traffic) harder or pointless. Unfortunatelly SSL is hard to setup on my webhost :( so at least hashing usernames and passwords is "safer" (yet unsafe) agreed?

Comment: @Jasd: I like your suggestion. Ironically that I would have to suggest my website visitors to enable a potential security risk (JS) for the sake of a safer password transmission :)

Comment: In my opinion, if you're not willing to go through the effort of SSL, then the username/password probably aren't worth protecting.  How would you feel if you got on your bank website, and it wasn't HTTPS, but don't worry!  They're using JS to hash your password.  Technically it works, but it's a bit non-standard and paranoid users will miss that fun little green lock in their address bar.

Comment: @Alex, your questions sounds like *there **is** some safe authentication **using javascript***! I was thinking about it but cannot find proper algorithm for it - please give me more info, post link etc. Thanks.

Comment: @Corbin: I am willing to go SSL. Idealy SSL in any case and this is the goal. On my webspace I and many others cannot use SSL for free and I have to accept that many won't do it. It is not GOOD. Still I consider plaintext transmission worse then hashed. It is not safe. The login to my site can be hacked still. The spice-hashed passwords will not be a security risk to the user for his other websites (in case he reuses his password, that happens:)

Comment: @Tomas: my thinking resulted in using AES preshared keys/passwords which salts. To store the key at the server I have to (only one time) fall back on a save channel (SSL-certificate of my webhost) [link](http://alexmahr.de/testseite/admin/). At login the users receives a salt then uses his password and the salt to generate a key in which he AES-encrypts his key (done in JS). the Server knowing the passwordhashes and salt can verify if correct. Requirement is the preshared keys/passwords.

Comment: @Alex, is the password encryption you used reversible (decryptable), or is it just one-way (i.e. hash)?

Comment: @Tomas: (are the PM?). Thank you for your interest! It is AES (yes can be reversed), which I think is no problem because the user knows his password which generates the key for him (in JS-code). Attacker would need to know the password to decrypt the message (which is the password itself + some spice). Once authetified a random (session key is generated) and used in the following communication. safe, right?

Comment: @Thomas: User(Client) knows password. The server knows a hash of this password too. For sake of authetification the password is hased and then encrypted with itself. This is send to server. If server can decrypt successfully with the hash password then this authentifies the user/session. Then the server generates a random sessionkey and send this key encrypted (for the last time with the hashed password as key) to the user. Afterwards AES-encrypt. No time a observer knows the passwordhash(=safe channel!). Only need is a safe setup (safe exchange of Pre-shared-key). This is done via SSL once!

Comment: @Alex (I don't understand what PM is..). So if I understand it right - please correct me: I suppose you don't store raw passwords in the DB, just hashes. The server generates the "spice" and sends it to the client. The client (in javascript) uses symmetric (? or public-private key?) AES cipher to encrypt `hash(password)+spice` using hash(password) as key. The server retrieves hash(password) from DB, decrypts and verifies. Right?

Comment: @Tomas Yes, correct I store a hashed form of the password in the DB (on the server). In the "woring example" I linked in the comment above the server does not even send a spice. It all starts with the client. The client hashes the password and encrypts it with itself (making it impossible to know what was the passwordhash). Yes again, the client uses symmetric AES cipher. The server verifies the authentification by decrypting the send message with the hash of the DB.

Comment: @Tomas: I don't mind continuing our talk here, I simply thought it might be braking StackOverflaw rules regarding (comments). I think you summerized the idea quite correctly in the comment. Indeed my JS(client) PHP(server) communication is AES (preshared key symmetrically encrypted). The preshared key is generated through the userpassword. Essential for working this way is that I have (one time) a safe channel to store the key on the server. This is done via a safe webftp-interface SSL-asymmetrically encrypted channel (which later on we can dispense of, what is the charm in my eyes)

Comment: @Tomas: this is just a lenghty way of giving an example of a IMO working JS-PHP encryption. not as swift as SSL (because in essence not a asymmetric encryption). PROS: need no own SSL certificate; is as to my understanding safe; CONS: need a safe channel to exchange the preshared keys. Regarding my initial question it is of little help to have this tool. Since I cannot provide an initial safe channel for new users (other then me).

Comment: @Alex, I guess it is not safe - if the salt (or spice how you call it) is not generated by the server, then the attacker can just sniff the encrypted message the client sends and then send the same thing and is there. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Tomas, in a way you you are right. with both. Without salt a sniffing can allow the "bad guy" to potentially fake-authentify himself with the saved message. This flaw, when using a salt can be prevented. Especially we need to restrict authentification attempts to 1 per salt (so sniffing and resending the message becomes useless).Even without salt the attacker will "only" be able to fake authentification but not be able to determine the password/passwordhash. This is for me an important aspect of security already. With the usage of a salt I think it will become safe. what do you think?

Comment: @Alex, yes, it seems so. I think it is easy to fix the flaw with salt actually. But the problem remains with the registration (exchaning pre-shared keys...). The thing with encrypted session key is clever! I guess widely used PHPSESSID is not encrypted and that's a fault!

Comment: @Alex, a question: where did you get the javascript code for AES from?

Comment: @Tomas: I am not 100% sure, but I think used this: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/aes-old.html. which should be available as LGPL licensed. I starting from this I adjusted somethings and developed a PHP equivalent (for the server side)

Comment: @Tomas, exactly the problem will be to have this initial "safe channel", which I already tried to mention among the CONS of this way. Still the encryption (which is after all quite standard AEStandard ;) is available for JS and PHP and so safer communication can be achieved, even without having to rely in the SSL. If the target case is not a "each day a new user" than it is not too troublesome to setup a "one-time-safe-channel" to exchange the pre-shared-(symmetric)keys.

Comment: @Alex, but how would you allow your users to register then, if your website doesn't support SSL?

Comment: @Tomas: compared to the "open door" authentification that and Hi-jacking via PHPSESSID or similar it might be already an improvement to use an unencrypted (unsafe) setup channel. The group of attacker to follow up communication will be reduced to those who already sniffed during the vulnerable unsecured initial setup. If you did not 24/7 you will be locked out, once you missed the setup. I understand there are many even far less safe and easier to hijack authentification systems out there. Granted also I would not rely on such a system for online-banking etc etc.

Comment: @Tomas. Having an initial safe channel can be for example a gmail account. As I understand nowadays online access to Gmail will be https and safe for the user. Ideally you can implement a "one-time-key" as part of the verification email. Unfortunatelly people with plaintext/unsecured email accounts will still remain vulnerable.... Still I think this way with using the "safe channel" email account would be good enough for me. After all I think there is not good case for my "solution" to encrypted communication. without SSL people will not trust (because url bar doesn't show SSL safety).

Comment: @Tomas: new users via exchange of presharked(one-time-key) via "safe"EMAIL. If email communication is not encrypted or intermediate partners (email providers) are distruted, this is of course no solution. But in many cases the level of security gained is already quite ok.

Comment: @Alex, so you will just generate password and send them via email? What if they want to change it? Anyway this is not safe, the emails are normally not encrypted.

Comment: @Alex, I just asked more focused question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9955286/. Let's wait for the answers.

Comment: @Tomas: I like your enthusiasm about this question! It is true that email could be potentially unsafe. The question would be "safe enough"? ex. For my 20 Euro bill the safety of my wallet is enough. For 100 kilos of gold even storing it in a bank can be "not safe" given the incentive for robbery.... Same here. Compared to plaintext passwords/username, a hashing with spice (even if retraceable is better!) is it good enough? it depends! While you are true with stating "email is not 100% safe" it is safer in some cases and in those cases this is worth the while.

Comment: @Tomas: No it is possible to create a password for the user, but not the only possible way. A good alternative to "pregenerated password" could be a **one time** sessionkey (being randomly created) and used for a encrypted connection in which the users chooses his own password, which then will be the entry to all subsequent symmetrically-encrypted communication.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you are using SSL, then the password is not being sent in plain text. Everything beyond the initial handshake is encrypted, and quite securely at that. Consider that this is the security that banks, the military, government all over the world rely upon daily. I'm not saying that you should trust it just because everyone else does ([argument from authority](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_authority)) - I'm just saying that if there were a problem with it, we'll hear about it right away.

Second of all, you don't ever really gain anything by client side hashing. The basic attack you're trying to prevent is a [man-in-the-middle (MITM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attack. Whether its someone eavesdropping on the connection, sniffing the password for a replay attack, or actively hijacking the session (i.e. pretending to be the server and the client to opposite ends of the connection), you can't really prevent it through additional security.

If you assume that the attacker can break through your SSL encryption, then any other token that relies on something the client software is doing or something that the server is sending along can be compromised. If its some client-side hash function, then the attacker can either learn what the function is by inspecting the webpage the server sends down or just sniff the hashed value and use it to impersonate the client when the attacker communicates with the server. If there is some secure key or token the server sends down for the client to use and respond with, the attacker can just intercept that.

I think what you're looking for is [two-factor authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-factor_authentication).